# Convert date to a string of valid datetime

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timezone

I am being passed a standard US date string such as "02/25/23".

I need to convert that to start of the day string with UTC time code, like this :

2023-02-25T00:00:00Z

I am trying to figure out how to get to the final string using datetime library. I'm first trying to convert the string to a usable datetime object like so :

```
start_datetime = datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 25, 0, 0, 0, 0, pytz.UTC)
```

But not sure how then convert that datetime object to a proper string as above?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example:

```py
import datetime as dt

s = '02/25/23'
dtime = dt.datetime.strptime(s, '%m/%d/%y')  # parse in US format (naive)
print(repr(dtime))
dtime = dtime.replace(tzinfo=dt.timezone.utc) # add timezone
print(repr(dtime))
print(dtime.isoformat())  # standard ISO format
print(dtime.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'))  # format requested
```

Output:

```
datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 25, 0, 0)
datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 25, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
2023-02-25T00:00:00+00:00
2023-02-25T00:00:00Z
```